# Корректно ли проверять наличие элемента таким способом: $('#element').length;

Tags: jquery

Корректно ли проверять наличие элемента в DOM таким способом:

```
$('#element').length;
```

Или jQuery вообще нет разницы есть элемент или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко, то да.

```
if ($(selector).length>0) {
    // Do something
}
```

Почитать [побольше](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery).

Comment: О.... Мерси!